# Is there a way to debug maven plugins artifact during project import in intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am trying to import a maven project in intellij which has complex pom dependencies.
Import fails with below error

> Can not set [class name from plugin] field [field name from plugin class] to null value

Apologies as I cannot write class name and field name due to NDA issues.

What I am looking for is a way to debug the artifact during import to find how the values are getting populated.

Comment: can you provide more info ... a stacktrace or something which can help to figure out your issue.

Comment: Can you build the same project by Maven on console with out IJ?

Comment: The problem seemed to be located within IntelliJ ...that means in otherwords you have to debug IntelliJ ... apart from that are you using the most recent version of IntelliJ.. .. also very important does your project build from plain command line as @SlawomirJaranowski already asked?

Comment: Yes Project builds perfectly fine from command line as well as can be imported from eclipse. I dont see a stacktrace its just a Error log that is displayed in the console even with Error Logging ON in Import Settings

Comment: This requires a further investigation.
Might be a good idea to submit a Support Ticket
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new
With logs and screenshots, if possible.